# input type text at center occupying the full width

Tags: css

Do you know how to have the text input occupying the full width of the col-md-7 div and positioned at the center of the red div (using bootstrap)?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nmdv2nj0/

html:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:red; padding:20px 0;">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col col-md-7" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe"/>
    </form>

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
```

will solve your problem.

I added jsfiddlle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nmdv2nj0/5/

Forgot to mention - you need to remove that form-inline class as well

Comment: maybe he needs the 'form-inline' class for another input, so, your solution won't work

Answer (score 0):

> Just add the  `width:100%!important;` in `<input type="text" id="inlineFormInputName2" />`

[Update jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmdv2nj0/2/)

```
#inlineFormInputName2{
  width:100%!important
}
```

Comment: !important is always bad idea.

Comment: id dont need important.

Answer (score 0):

add a class like this to the input

```
.w-l{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

if you see your css, '.form-inline' will make the child '.form-control' items to have 'width:auto'

```
@media (min-width: 576px){
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

so, the solution is force the input to be full width

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg w-l"
```

Comment: you should never ever use !important, unless it's really really important :)

Comment: it need to be '!important' since bootstrap override the '.w-l' class, unless he puts his custom css after bootstrap, it need to be '!important!' :)

Comment: check solution I wrote for this, he's using bootstrap 4 so he needs to resolve it proper way !important is always workaround.

Comment: you just removed the 'form-inline' class from the 'form' tag, thats why your solution works, because 'form-control' is 100% width, but not inside a 'form-inline'

Comment: form-inline should be used to display multiple elements in one row he has only one element, so naturally he doesn't need it. For more info check documentation:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

Comment: it's only an example, he eventually will add more elements.. regards :)